# DRF: HyperlinkSerializer with url param

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I've spent several hours trying to solve the common error `Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "event-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the`lookup_field`attribute on this field.` and have read every possibly related question.

I think my issue has to do with the path I serve my API on, which includes a url param. I'm not doing any namespacing of my API.

Application `urls.py`.

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register("event", api_views.EventViewSet, base_name='event')

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('server.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    path('api/v1/eventID/<str:eventID>/', include(router.urls)),
    path(r'api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls'))
]
```

I use the url param to filter results in my view:

Viewset

```
class EventViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = EventSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Event.objects.filter(id=self.kwargs["eventID"])
```

My serializer is extremely basic:

```
from server.models import Event

class EventSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = "__all__"
```

If I change my route to not include a url param, like

```
path('api/v1/eventID/', include(router.urls)),
```

and update the queryset to simply return `Event.objects.all()`, the hyperlinked url for my `event` is returned with the response without error.

I've tried editing the `url` property on the serializer, which seems to control the attempted `reverse` but I don't know what to add here to make it match my path.

Comment: Because of the parameter, all reverse calls will need that arg/kwarg passed as well so it'll look like reverse('event-detail', args=[eventID]) as opposed to just reverse('event-detail'). You'll have to dig through drf's source to figure out how they build the hyperlink field. Anyway I suggest you read through the tutorial again. I think you may have a few concepts backwards. Particularly this part: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/6-viewsets-and-routers/

Comment: Thanks for the response. I thought about and read more into this issue, and stepped through the DRF code a lot. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#custom-hyperlinked-fields is almost exactly what I wanted to do, not sure how I missed this article. Overriding get_url and manually adding eventID to kwargs more or less fixed the problem.